# Homebridge Nest Error on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: automation, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I've installed homebridge and homebridge-nest with success on my Raspberry Pi 3 (running Raspian).

After copying the config.json file into the appropriate directory and running the homebridge command, I get the following error:

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ homebridge
>   *** WARNING**  The program 'node' uses the Apple Bonjour compatibility layer of Avahi.
>    **WARNING**  Please fix your application to use the native API of Avahi!
>    **WARNING**  For more information see http://0pointer.de/avahi-compat?s=libdns_sd&e=node
>    **WARNING**  The program 'node' called 'DNSServiceRegister()' which is not supported (or only supported partially) in the Apple Bonjour
>   compatibility layer of Avahi.
>    **WARNING**  Please fix your application to use the native API of Avahi!
>    **WARNING *** For more information see http://0pointer.de/avahi-compat?s=libdns_sd&e=node&f=DNSServiceRegister
>   [2018-3-4 14:29:38] Loaded plugin: homebridge-nest [2018-3-4 14:29:38]
>   Registering platform 'homebridge-nest.Nest' [2018-3-4 14:29:38] ---
>   [2018-3-4 14:29:38] Loaded config.json with 1 accessories and 1
>   platforms. [2018-3-4 14:29:38] --- [2018-3-4 14:29:38] Loading 1
>   platforms... [2018-3-4 14:29:38] [Nest] Initializing Nest platform...
>   [2018-3-4 14:29:38] [Nest] Fetching Nest devices. [2018-3-4 14:29:38]
>   Loading 1 accessories...
>   /usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/lib/api.js:64
>         throw new Error("The requested accessory '" + name + "' was not registered by any plugin.");
>         ^
>
> Error: The requested accessory 'Nest' was not registered by any
>   plugin.
>       at API.accessory (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/lib/api.js:64:13)
>       at Server._loadAccessories (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/lib/server.js:264:42)
>       at Server.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/lib/server.js:86:38)
>       at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/lib/cli.js:40:10)
>       at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/homebridge/bin/homebridge:17:22)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:608:3 pi@raspberrypi:~ $

My config.json file looks like this:

```
 {
    "bridge": {
        "name": "Homebridge",
        "username": "CC:22:3D:E3:CE:30",
        "port": 51826,
        "pin": "031-45-154"
    },

"description": "This is an example configuration file with one fake accessory and one fake platform. You can use this as a template for creating your own configuration file containing devices you actually own.",

"accessories": [{
    "accessory": "Nest",
    "name": "Nest"
}],

"platforms": [{
    "platform": "Nest",


    "clientId": "ID from Nest Dev",
    "clientSecret": "secret code from Nest Dev",
    "code": "code generated from Nest Dev"
}]
}
```

Banging my head! Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved!

I had to remove the "accessories" portion of the json file.  Rebooted and now works.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the homebridge-nest GitHub page. Looks like they updated their config, use one of their examples. (This is coming from a ten-year-old, so I may be wrong)